# MongoDB "join" (1-to-many and many-to-many manual references?) Help needed. NO ENBEDDING METHODS

Tags: mongodb

I am new with MongoDB, I know quite some stuff in MySQL. I work in RoboMongo.

Let's say I have two collections:
Instruments:

```
db.createCollection('Instruments');
db.Instruments.insert(
[{
    instrumentID : 1,
    instrumentName : "Squier",
    instrumentManufacturerID : 3,
    instrumentMadeIn: 'someCountry'
},{
...
])
```

and Manufacturers:

```
db.createCollection('Manufacturers')
db.Manufacturers.insert([
{
     manufactID : 1,
     manufactName : 'Fender',
     manufactCountry : 'United States',
     manufactFounded : 1946
},{
...
])
```

I want to "SELECT" (find?) the instruments whom manufacturers' country is the 'United States'
...and I want to "UPDATE" all the 'Fender' instruments' instrumentMadeIn country to 'Japan'

I don't want to nest the ManufacturerInformation inside each Instrument, becouse repeating the same information oven and over again is a waste of time and space.

I saw some code, where the ID field was called '_id' and had a large object value. It had to do something with the references, not sure tho.

I just want some **simple codes** to achieve my goals, no need for large explanations, maybe some short, simple ones, but that's all I ask. I won't be using MongoDB ever, just for this assignment. Thank you!

Comment: Your title is very broad and unclear. Please check [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask, having a clear title helps getting others to see your question. To edit your question, click the "edit" link on the bottom.

Comment: You can't "join", you could rely on embedded documents

Comment: The user mentioned that the document should not be embedded.

Comment: *I don't want to nest the ManufacturerInformation inside each Instrument, becouse repeating the same information oven and over again is a waste of time and space.* You are still thinking MySQL and not MongoDB. In a document-database, denormalizing your data is not such a mortal sin as it is in a relational database.

Comment: @Philipp , I know I'm thinking in mySQL, but I do not need mongo knowledge, I just have to finish a single assignment, and after that I'm off with DB.

Comment: Read [Data Modelling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) from the core documentation. And read the whole section as it provides **many** examples of embedded or referenced contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB is a document database, not a relational database. It does not do JOINs. A schema which depends on "JOINs" between collections to do its basic operations is not a good fit for a document database and should be denormalized to a single collection with embedded data. When you feel icky about this, you should consider to use a relational database instead.

When you must perform such an operation, you need to do this on the client-side by running multiple queries. You didn't specify the programming language your application is written in, so I will explain how to do it in the mongo shell.

```
// get the id of Fender
var manufacturerId = db.Manufacturers.findOne({"manufactName" : "Fender",}).manufactID;
// update all instruments with that manufacturer ID which are made in japan
db.Instruments.update(
    { "instrumentManufacturerID" : manufacturerId, "instrumentMadeIn": "Japan" },
    { $set: { "foo":"bar"}},
    { multi:true }
);
```

Yes, it is ugly and slow that you need two queries for such a simple operation, but that's what you get when you try to use a screwdriver as a hammer.

Regarding your question about the `_id` field: Every document gets this field automatically, and when it is set automatically it is set to a (practically) globally unique ObjectId. You can use this as an unique ID for documents, but you don't have to. When your data already has an unique key, you can also set `_id` to that value yourself.